# Is it possible to reverse a column transformation in Spotfire, and if not, what are the alternatives?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I've made the mistake of using the 'Calculate and Replace Column' feature to replace the wrong column, and realized after the fact. The column I replaced corresponds to last names and is important. I would like to retrieve this column but maintain my other 15 or so data transformations. Ideally, I would like to remove this transformation, but I've come up empty so far. Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried adding the 'last name' column again from the same external source, using >Insert >Columns...  I also tried renaming this column to avoid the data transformation. Unfortunately, this resulted in an entirely empty column, so it did not successfully match to the table or was affected by the transformation..
2. I checked the source information, and found exactly the 3-4 lines that I wish were not there. I thought it might be possible to edit this but haven't found a way. This seems like it would be the easiest.
3. Another idea I had was I could replace the data table with the same source, and repeat all of the transformations from the replace data table dialogue (excluding the bad one). This is my next plan of attack, but I figured I would come on here to see if there's an easier way first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is currently a ticket with Tibco that has requested this. you can contact them and get you're account set up to notify you if the Program Manager puts this into the next version/update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good News for YOU!!! @jeremyVollen.
It is possible to 'edit' your transformation per Tibco article 44098.

> Resolution:   If there are more then one transformations on a data table and you need to edit any of those transformation, follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Go To Edit >> Data Table Properties.
> 2. Select the desired data table inside which the transformation has been added and click on Refresh Data > With Prompt.
> 3. A new window will pop up which will allow you to make the desired changes in each of the transformations.

Comment: As niko stated I thought recreating the whole transformation was the only way. Hiding this functionality under "Refresh Data with Prompt" is not very initiative, at least to me! Anyway this makes it so much easier! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately it is NOT possible to reverse data table transformations.

it IS possible to undo the transformations with Edit>>Undo or CTRL+Z, but that's as far as it goes.

my strategy for dealing with this is (in accordance with your #3) to visit Edit>>Data Table Properties, select the table I'm interested in, select Source Information, then copy the contents of the textarea and paste it into notepad. then, I'll File>>Replace Data Table and start over from the beginning while keeping the notepad open so I don't miss any steps.

I realize it's not ideal, but there is unfortunately not another way.

Comment: There is currently a ticket with Tibco that has requested this.  you can contact them and get you're account set up to notify you if the Program Manager puts this into the next version/update.

Comment: see my answer below for instructions on how to do this.